# HTTP Host header as route value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to serve multiple virtual hosts from the same code base.  One thought I had was pass the HTTP Host header as a route value because I did't want to rely on HttpContext in the controllers because of unit testability.

I had planned on exposing this route value in a controller base class or something like that.  I tried passing as a route value like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

This yields an HttpException: Request is not available in this context.

Any ideas or suggestions on a better way to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be fine relying on the Context when testing your controller. The routing system has been designed with testability in mind so you could set a mock context that provides the right URL when your tests run.

The reason why your code does not work is because you are probabling invoking it from the global `Application_Start` event which happens before the first request comes in. This means that an HttpContext object is not available at that time.

Comment: Request not being available in Application_Start totally makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try modifying your `HomeController` as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var request = HttpContext.Request.Url;

    if (request != null && request.AbsoluteUri.Contains("domain.com")) {
        //take the desired action and redirect here
    }

    //the rest of home controller logic
}
```